# Android broadcast receiver not fire after screen off

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm using broadcast receiver to read Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK and make it play an audio from a service every minute. Everything works fine except when the screen is off, it no longer sounds. If i keep the screen on or plug in the usb cable with the screen off, it runs back on. Please help, thank!

PS. After a couple of tests, I found out that this only happens on my android 2.3.6 phone, on the other hand on my 4.1.2, it runs without problem.

```
    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    registerReceiver(new TickReceiver(), new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cuckoo);

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    notifyMe();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {


    clearNotification();

    if (mp != null){
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }

}

public void notifyMe() {
    note = new Notification(R.drawable.front, "Message Inbound!",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            LeftAndRightActivity.class), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Title...", "Subtitle", i);

    note.flags = note.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
}

public void clearNotification() {
    mgr.cancel(NOTIFY_ME_ID);
}

public void playBeep() {

    mp.start();

}

public class TickReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        playBeep();

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the min sdk you have kept in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

try doing this in your oncreate:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```